# Is there any way to split payment between multiple accounts using paypal API?

Tags: node.js, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

we need to split the payement of users between multiple accounts (partners) using the paypal API, for example if a user pays $100, account A gets 30% and account B gets 70%, we are using nodejs as our development envirement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the payment into an account you control, you could (as a separate transaction) send some of that amount using Payouts, which you can [request access to](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/integrate-api/#link-knowbeforeyoucode). Approval may or may not be granted for your use case.